# How to get dynamic list view of contact records for community

Tags: list-view, community-builder

I want to have a list view of contact records to show on community based on the logged in user on community

I tried the list view filters but there is no dynamic option.

I want something like where account Id equals currentUser.accountID in the list view filter

Answer (score 1):

- Create a formula field on User called `Account_Id__c`. It is defined as `Contact.AccountId` and is a field of Text type.
- Create a formula field on the Contact with name `Is_My_Contact__c` and define it to be

**Checkbox**

with formula

```
$User.Account_Id__c = AccountId /* is user's account same as contact's account */
```

Then change your listview filter to be simply `Is_My_Contact__c = true`

*N.B. not tested; You may need to use CASESAFEID to ensure you are always comparing 18 character Ids*

> This gets around the issue you mentioned in your comment about `$User.Contact.Account.Id` converting to `$User.Id` after saving the formula

Comment: When I enter the formula and hit save and go back again and click edit on the field the formula becomes $User.Id = AccountId. Why is this happening?

Comment: I edited my answer @Anwar